# How to create a SearchView in Actionbar for a ListView that uses Images?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, searchview

I have tried to create a SearchView with just a simple ListView without Images and it worked. But after i added images to the listview... the SearchView does not work. I am new to this so please help. Thanks in advance.

This my main code

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

ListView listview; SearchView sv; SearchManager searchManager;
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter;
String [] Topics = {"ABC","BCD","CDE","DEF","EFG","FGH","GHI","HIJ"};
CustomAdapter adapter;
String[] NOS;
int[] images = {R.drawable.logheader,R.drawable.logheader,R.drawable.logheader,R.drawable.logheader,R.drawable.logheader,R.drawable.logheader,R.drawable.logheader,R.drawable.logheader};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


         adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,Topics,images);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sell);
    sv =(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_Action);
    searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    myAdapter = adapter;
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


final Assigner assigner = new Assigner();

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    String Op = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,Op, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        NOS= assigner.rept(position);
                        Intent into = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,FourthActivity.class);
                        into.putExtra("well",NOS);
                        startActivity(into);

                }}

    );

}

boolean twice;

public void onBackPressed() {

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {



    }


    if (twice == true) {
        Intent intt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intt.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intt);
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Press BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            twice = false;
        }
    }, 3000);
    twice = true;
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.second,menu);

    sv = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_Action).getActionView();
    sv.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    sv.setQueryHint("Search any topic...");

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            myAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.search_Action) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Post your code here for better help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-search-collapsible-view-in-android/), This is exactly what you looking for,,Just add image in listview

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    EditText editsearch;
    String[] rank;
    String[] country;
    String[] population;
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> arraylist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        // Generate sample data
        rank = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

        country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
                "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria", "Bangladesh",
                "Russia", "Japan" };

        population = new String[] { "1,354,040,000", "1,210,193,422",
                "315,761,000", "237,641,326", "193,946,886", "182,912,000",
                "170,901,000", "152,518,015", "143,369,806", "127,360,000" };

        // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) {
            WorldPopulation wp = new WorldPopulation(rank[i], country[i],
                    population[i]);
            // Binds all strings into an array
            arraylist.add(wp);
        }

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    // Create the options menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Get the options menu view from menu.xml in menu folder
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        // Locate the EditText in menu.xml
        editsearch = (EditText) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();

        // Capture Text in EditText
        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        // Show the search menu item in menu.xml
        MenuItem menuSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

        menuSearch.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

            // Menu Action Collapse
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // Empty EditText to remove text filtering
                editsearch.setText("");
                editsearch.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }

            // Menu Action Expand
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                // Focus on EditText
                editsearch.requestFocus();

                // Force the keyboard to show on EditText focus
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Show the settings menu item in menu.xml
        MenuItem menuSettings = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings);

        // Capture menu item clicks
        menuSettings.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Do something here
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing here!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }

        });

        return true;
    }

    // EditText TextWatcher
    private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = editsearch.getText().toString()
                    .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
}
```